# MongoDB get an item out of db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So i have implemented a mongodb on my nodejs server. And what I have done is store users via:

```js
function insertUser() {
    var collection = dbb.collection('user');
        var user1 = {name: user, token: token};
        collection.insert(user1, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
}
```

```js
function findUserByName(devName) {
 var collection = dbb.collection('user');
    collection.find({name: devName}).toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else if (result.length) {
            console.log('Found: ', result);
   
            selectedUserToken = result.token;
        } else {
            console.log('No document found');
            insertUser();
        }
        dbb.close();
    });
}
```

So result will equal:

```
Found:  [ { _id: 57be1cadc281c03ea116c9ab,
    name: 'Austin Hunter',
    token: 'dJyXVjMJk08kXWrua8SUjKb....SxACihKZoR53y_wOZmcFNKMmD5q99QNvsp3flL' } ]
```

My question is, how can I get that token out to equal selectedUserToken so I can send a push notification with gcm? Right now result.token is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `findOne()` instead of `find()` since you only expect a single result back:

```
function findUserByName(devName) {
    var collection = dbb.collection('user');
    collection.findOne({name: devName}, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else if (result) {
            console.log('Found: ', result);

            selectedUserToken = result.token;
        } else {
            console.log('No document found');
            insertUser();
        }
        dbb.close();
    });
}
```

But if you wanted to leave your code as is with the find() you would just retrieve the first element of the resulting array retrieved by find()

```
function findUserByName(devName) {
    var collection = dbb.collection('user');
    collection.find({name: devName}).toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else if (result.length) {
            console.log('Found: ', result);

            selectedUserToken = result[0].token;
        } else {
            console.log('No document found');
            insertUser();
        }
        dbb.close();
    });
}
```

Comment: it still isn't working properly using the findOne method.

Comment: I am still getting undefined for console.log(selectedUserToken)

Comment: I will post a pastern of my entire Nodejs server code. So you can see the context.

http://pastebin.com/v1ij99fL

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to access `selectedUserToken` before it's been set.  This `console.log("TOKEN: " + selectedUserToken);` is happening before this `selectedUserToken = result;` which occurs in the asynchronous callback of your collection.find().  (also that last bit should be changed to `selectedUserToken = result.token;` right?).

Comment: Right. So what would be the procedure to doing what I am trying to do? Accessing an element out of a MongoDB to use in a post

Comment: See changes here http://pastebin.com/jiHsV3RM to findUserByName and sendToAndroid

Comment: fantastic help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `result[0].token`, because result is an array of user items.